# How to matplotlib draw figure with different spacing

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

How to matplotlib draw figure with different spacing?

specifically, how to draw this one?

[image]

Comment: This is not a code writing service here, but you should look into ``pyplot.step``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plot shown in the question is plotted on a `'logit'` scale.

```
ax.set_xscale('logit')
ax.set_yscale('logit')
```

You may refer to the [scales example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/scales/scales.html).